# ssh login as other user starts autojack and kills current jack session running in desktop

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I am using Ubuntu Studio 22.04, it's working as expected.

I use ansible to automate some tasks and it uses a ssh login as root. This ssh login starts autojack as root and kills the currently running jack session running as the logged in user on the desktop.

I'm trying to track down how/why autojack is being started via a ssh login, any pointers on which direction to start looking?

Comment: This hasn't yet been resolved, and its caused by any ssh login including the desktop user thats logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug.

To fix, I had to run as root `systemctl edit --user studio.service`
and set `ExecStart=/bin/true` so autojack would not spawn as root when ssh login was completed.